# How to get the equivalent of chmod 600 using icacls on Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I'm looking for a way to achieve the equivalent of `chmod 600` on Windows using the `icacls` utility. For the user part I got the `rw` permission by using `icacls file /inheritance:r /grant:r %USERNAME%:(R,W)`. Now, I'm having troubles with denying all the other users from any access to the file. I could explicitly deny every existing user but any users created after the denial will still have access to the file. Is there any good way to deny all the users except for me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Is there any good way to deny all the users except for me?" It's not possible on Windows. An administrator will always have access.